# «Сажала деревья в первомайской степи». Стоит ли повышать название?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

«...сажала деревья в первомайской степи». Степь в Первомайском районе Крыма. Стоит ли повышать название степи?

Answer (score 1):

"Первомайская степь"

Написанное со строчной, похоже на ребус: дагадайся, что это значит.
Написанное с прописной, говорит, что это название степи.
Я бы искал третий путь.

Например: **В Первомайском районе сажала деревья в степи** или **Сажала деревья в степях Первомайского района**

Comment: следующее предложение говорит про Первомайский район итд...

Comment: Лучше было бы, если бы предыдущее предложение говорило про Первомайский район.

Comment: Можно попытаться обойтись без проблемного слова: ... сажала деревья в степи. И теперь здесь, в Первомайском районе (Крыма), сады зацветут.

Comment: может, просто написать со строчной и делов...?!

Comment: Не видя контекста, из двух зол (если они неизбежны) я бы выбрал прописную (может и не точно, но ясно)